# Can I launch Containing App from Watch App Extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, beta, watchkit

I am writing WatchKit based app.

How can I launch Containing App from Watch APP extension?

1) User click a button on Watch App

2) Action sent to Watch App Extension

3) I want to launch Hosting App (main app on iPhone) by URL scheme and let host app to response to 
user's click on Watch.

Can I do that? Are Watch extension's communication to host only limited to NSUserDefaults?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is exactly a duplicate of the question marked. This question concerns launching the containing app through a URL scheme, which would be a user facing operation. The other question is about reusing code between the extension and the containing app, which can be addressed through frameworks, etc.

Comment: You can use (BOOL)openParentApplication:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
                        reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo,
                                        NSError *error))reply

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like Beta 2 has more ways to handle extension and containing app communications.